# How remove all rows contain specific text?

Tags: text-editing

Windows 10, Emacs 25.1
Suppose I has the next text

111111111111111111

**hello**

22222222

aaaa**hello**

3333333333333333333333333333333

aabbbbbbbb**hello**cccccdddddddd

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

cccccccccccccccc

dddddddd

r**hello**rraaaa111111111

I want to delete all rows that contain text **hello**.
How I can do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the command `delete-matching-lines` via

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `delete-matching-lines` <kbd>RET</kbd> `hello` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

Note that tab-expansion helps a lot with typing command names at the minibuffer. You just need to type

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `dele` <kbd>TAB</kbd> `ma` <kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd> `hello` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

Comment: I use helm mode. It's show all commands. It's very helpful. Thanks. Command "delete-matching-lines" work fine.

Comment: In case anybody is wondering, `delete-matching-lines` is an alias for `flush-lines`. I came here to recommend that solution and then discovered that they are the same.

Comment: Is there an analog for cutting?

Comment: @Erwann Does `kill-matching-lines` what you mean by "cutting"? There is also `copy-matching-lines` if needed.

Comment: @Erwann "Cut" and "Paste" in other applications are very close to "Kill" and "Yank" in Emacs.